# MySql Choose users by their latest date

Tags: mysql

Try to get the salary from the Employes by the latest date but getting multiple outputs. Tried with distinct also didn't work.
I am sure only like one word is missing for me to solve this :D

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name, salary, to_date
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN salaries s
 ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no
 AND salary >= 70000   // Here I miss the line which will only take the latest date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL versions 8+, `ROW_NUMBER` is a good way to handle this requirement:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name, salary, to_date,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name
                                       ORDER BY to_date DESC) rn
    FROM employees e
    LEFT JOIN salaries s ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no AND s.salary >= 70000
)

SELECT first_name, last_name, salary, to_date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Note that this answer assumes that the combination of an employee's first and last name would always be unique.  In general, it would be much better to use a unique employee ID of some kind here.

This answer might not be complete without a version which would also run on MySQL 5.7 or earlier:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, s1.salary, s1.to_date
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN salaries s1 ON e.emp_no = s1.emp_no AND s1.salary >= 70000
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT emp_no, MAX(to_date) AS max_to_date
    FROM salaries
    GROUP BY emp_no
) s2
    ON s1.emp_no = s2.emp_no AND s1.to_date = s2.max_to_date;
```